# How to customize the way JAXB parses xml?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jaxb

I am working with the JAXB since 2 days only so please forgive me if my question is too easy. Actually I tried to google for that but I  didn't find anything interesting. 
So I used JAXB to generate java classes based on xsd schema. I tested, everything works, when I make JAXB parse the xml (which satisfies schemas) I receive real objects full of data. That is great. 
My question is, if it is possible to generate some kind of dictionary during the parsing of the xml? Is it somehow possible to register a handler which will be called during parsing ? 
How to achieve it?

For example let's say in the xml which is currently being parsed there is a line like this:

```
<BookedTrip Tattoo="2" RPH="100" Direction="Inward" BookStatus="HK">
```

I would like to be able to extract something like `BookedTrip.Direction = Inward`.
I guess I can do it using some kind of handlers for the XML parser.

Comment: could u clearify where that line would be? in a cdata block?

Comment: sorry I didn't notice that it is not correctly displayed. I hope now it is clearer :)

Comment: so you want to read the value of an attribute of your element?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JAXB location in file for unmarshalled objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7079796/jaxb-location-in-file-for-unmarshalled-objects)

Comment: Have a look at the following blog: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/08/using-unmarshallerlistener-to-capture.html

Comment: I don't think it is a duplication.
@Wandang In general I want to do some additional actions, value of this attribute is read and set in the java classes to which this xml is mapped, but for some values (like the one I mentioned) I want to store them in additional place/data structure. I just want to be able to customize the parsing process.