# Why cannot JAXB find the number of XML row?

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, websphere, xsd-validation

I try to unmarshall XML to validate some values. If particular value is invalid, I want to know a line from which the value came. Here is my code which is inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7081390/5661496).

Some errors can be encountered by ValidationEventHandler:

```
public class XmlErrorHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {
    // private fields and methods are omitted, constructor is default
    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        generateReportObjectsForXsdError(event.getMessage(), event.getLocator().getLineNumber());
        return true;
    }
}
```

Others demand some logic to detect. So, I save XML line number for every deserialized object:

```
public class LocationListener
        extends Unmarshaller.Listener {
    private XMLStreamReader xsr;
    private Map<Object, Location> locations;

    public LocationListener(XMLStreamReader xsr) {
        super();
        this.xsr = xsr;
        this.locations = new HashMap<>();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeUnmarshal(Object target, Object parent) {
        locations.put(target, xsr.getLocation());
    }

    public Map<Object, Location> getLocations() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(locations);
    }
}
```

The unmarshal action is performed with following code:

```
public static <T> T xmlToObject(
            XMLStreamReader data, Class factory, Unmarshaller.Listener listener, ValidationEventHandler eventHandler,
            Schema schema) throws JAXBException {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(factory);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setListener(listener);
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(eventHandler);
        unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);

        return (T)unmarshaller.unmarshal(data);
}
```

XMLStreamReader data is the same object as listener.xsr.

Well, the code works like a charm on my tomcat.

The problem is when I use IBM WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.10 (which is target platform) I am always getting -1 as `event.getLocator().getLineNumber()` in `XmlErrorHandler.handleEvent()` and `xsr.getLocation().getLineNumber()` in `LocationListener.beforeUnmarshal()`.

The problem doesn't depend on JAXB implementation. (I have tried IBM WAS, Eclipce MOXy and Java reference implementations).

So, my question is what should I do to get line numbers?

Thanks

UPD: I know that documentation states that `getLineNumber()` returns -1 when there are no available number lines. But why can it be unavailable on WAS?

Answer (score 0):

The API spec indicates that `Location.getLineNumber()` returns `-1` when no line number is avaliable.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/Location.html

What makes you think there are even any lines?
Does a stream usually have lines?

If you know the "value" that caused the error, and you have a source file that has lines (which the stream itself does not) then you can search the file for the "value" and find the line number.

Comment: Yes, lines exist. And JAXB can extract them, when executed on tomcat. And yes, I can find the value, so should my application :)